# Printf-Style Assertions using CPPUnit

Tags: c++, cppunit

Does CPPUnit have any functionality that would allow me to do `printf`-style assertions? For example:

```
CPPUNIT_ASSERT("Actual size: %d", p->GetSize(), p->GetSize() == 0);
```

I know this is not a valid CPPUNIT_ASSERT - I am just using this as an example.

I found `CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE(message,condition)` which takes a string and then the condition to evaluate but no luck getting the value into the assert.

Comment: why can't you just use `sprintf` to put the value into the `message` string and then call `CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE(message,condition)` with it?

Comment: @PaulEvans I was trying to get around using C-style functions in C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
#define CPPUNIT_ASSERT_STREAM(MSG, CONDITION) \
    do { \
        std::ostringstream oss; \
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE(\
            static_cast<std::ostringstream &>(oss << MSG).str(), \
            CONDITION); \
    } while (0)

CPPUNIT_ASSERT_STREAM("Actual size: " << p->GetSize(), p->GetSize() == 0);
```

The above macro can also be combined with [Boost.format](http://www.boost.org/libs/format/):

```
CPPUNIT_ASSERT_STREAM(boost::format("Actual size: %d") % p->GetSize(),
                      p->GetSize() == 0);
```

Comment: Why do you need `do {}while (0)` ?

Comment: @sasha.sochka The `do{}while(0)` makes the lines to one compound statement. The ';' will complete this perfectly and the macro doesn't depend on surrounding context.

Comment: @jxh So I guess the answer is no and that I have to create my own macro?

Comment: @larrylampco: I did not find any existing feature of CPPUnit that provided formatted assertions.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [`CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL`](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/lastest/group___assertions.html#ga3), which takes an actual and expected value. This pretty much eliminates the need for formatting a string, as the actual and expected values will be printed in the failure message.

You could also copy the implementation of this macro and the function it invokes and add additional macros for other types of comparisons. Another idea I tried out would be to use operator overloading to capture the value out of an expression. This (ab)uses operator overloading to capture the expression, but it seems perhaps a bit too hackish. I have included it to give you an idea of what is possible, but would not recommend its use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class ExpressionPrinter
{
public:
  std::ostringstream result;

  template<typename T> ExpressionPrinter& operator<<(const T& other)
  {
    result << other;
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T> ExpressionPrinter& operator<(const T& other)
  {
    result << " < ";
    result << other;
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T> ExpressionPrinter& operator<=(const T& other)
  {
    result << " <= ";
    result << other;
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T> ExpressionPrinter& operator>(const T& other)
  {
    result << " > ";
    result << other;
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T> ExpressionPrinter& operator>=(const T& other)
  {
    result << " >= ";
    result << other;
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T> ExpressionPrinter& operator==(const T& other)
  {
    result << " == ";
    result << other;
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T> ExpressionPrinter& operator!=(const T& other)
  {
    result << " != ";
    result << other;
    return *this;
  }
};

#define ASSERT(X) doAssert((X), (ExpressionPrinter() << X));

void doAssert(bool result, const ExpressionPrinter& message)
{
  std::cout << "Result: " << result << ", Expression: " << message.result.str() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int i = 1, j = 2;

  ASSERT(i < j);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do like this macro, however it doesn't allow for assertions other than equality. How do you use greater than or less than?

Comment: I have added a few additional comments.

Answer (score 0):

I use selfdefined assert to print all needed info:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define ASSERT(v, msg)
#else
#define ASSERT(v, msg) \
if (v) {} else { \
  std::cerr << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " assertion failed: " \
            << #v << " = " << (v) << "\n" << msg << std::endl; \
  abort(); \
}
#endif
```

To use:

```
#include <iostream>
...
ASSERT( p->GetSize() == 0, p->GetSize() );
```

or

```
ASSERT( p->GetSize() == 0, "Actual size: " << p->GetSize() << " Actual size * 2: " << p->GetSize()*2 );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
...
ASSERT( p->GetSize() == 0, p->GetSize() );
```